# JOIN in the same table and FOREACH with IMPLODE to get menu

Tags: php, mysql, menu

**Table:** `categories`

```
╔═════════════╦═══════════════════╦═════════════════╗
║ id_category ║ category_name     ║ category_father ║
╠═════════════╬═══════════════════╬═════════════════╣
║  1          ║ Home              ║   0             ║
║  2          ║ Category_1        ║   1             ║
║  3          ║ Category_2        ║   1             ║
║  4          ║ Category_3        ║   1             ║
║  5          ║ Category_4        ║   1             ║
║  6          ║ Category_5        ║   1             ║
║  7          ║ Sub_Category_1    ║   2             ║
║  8          ║ Sub_Category_2    ║   2             ║
║  9          ║ Sub_Category_3    ║   2             ║
║  10         ║ Sub_Category_4    ║   2             ║
║  11         ║ Sub_Category_5    ║   3             ║
║  12         ║ Sub_Category_6    ║   3             ║
║  13         ║ Sub_Category_7    ║   3             ║
║  14         ║ Sub_Category_8    ║   3             ║
║  15         ║ Sub_Category_9    ║   3             ║
╚═════════════╩═══════════════════╩═════════════════╝
```

I am using `meekro.class` to consult my database, right now I'm building the menu of my application, but I need to do `JOIN` to the same `table` to show the `category_name` instead of the `id` of `category_father` and I can not.

I also need to show in list form the main categories and below the subcategories. I intend to use only one level of `sub categories` so this table structure should work.

**This is my query:**

```
$querycategories = DB::query("SELECT * FROM categories");
foreach ($querycategories as $row) {
    echo "<b>" . $row['category_name'] . "</b>";
    echo "<ul>";
        echo "<li>" . $row['category_father'] . "</li>";
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Of course, with this consultation, I get a disaster, that's why I come to you to get help!

**This is what I hope to obtain:**

**Category_1**

- Sub_Category_1
- Sub_Category_2
- Sub_Category_3
- Sub_Category_4

**Category_2**

- Sub_Category_5
- Sub_Category_6
- Sub_Category_7
- Sub_Category_8
- Sub_Category_9

**Category_3**

**Category_4**

**Category_5**

I hope you can help me, it takes almost 1 hour to write the question, please, take 5 minutes of your day to help me, thanks in advance!

Comment: So, what does the disaster look like?  and yes, I believe it did take you a while to write your question -- pretty double-line table mock-up.

Comment: @mickmackusa like this: https://imgur.com/a/IQkAg

Comment: you cannot join because you don't know ah the syntax is, or there is some other impediment? Is it the SQL you want help with or the presentation od the result? ... unclear ...  `SELECT *  FROM categories c1 inner join categories c2 on c1.id_category = c2.category_father`

Comment: @Used_By_Already ok this seems to work, I do not get an error (this helps me) but how do I show the name instead of the id?

Comment: by choosing the name column .... ?  in truth no sql query should use `select *` they should alsways specify column names. In many places we use it just to abbreviate our answers, but that isn't a recommendation to use it in production. When you loop through he result, pick out the column(s) you want to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` will deliver the necessary null values to build your unordered list.

I say use this: (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e7fe/3)

```
SELECT A.category_name AS parent, B.category_name AS child
FROM categories A 
LEFT JOIN categories B on A.id_category=B.category_father
WHERE A.category_father=1
ORDER BY parent
```

Output:

```
╔════════════╦════════════════╗
║   parent   ║     child      ║
╠════════════╬════════════════╣
║ Category_1 ║ Sub_Category_1 ║
║ Category_1 ║ Sub_Category_2 ║
║ Category_1 ║ Sub_Category_3 ║
║ Category_1 ║ Sub_Category_4 ║
║ Category_2 ║ Sub_Category_5 ║
║ Category_2 ║ Sub_Category_6 ║
║ Category_2 ║ Sub_Category_7 ║
║ Category_2 ║ Sub_Category_8 ║
║ Category_2 ║ Sub_Category_9 ║
║ Category_3 ║ (null)         ║
║ Category_4 ║ (null)         ║
║ Category_5 ║ (null)         ║
╚════════════╩════════════════╝
```

PHP Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4103cd93799446a5274dc80f8b6ac241084ad1fa))

```
$querycategories=[
    ['parent'=>'Category_1','child'=>'Sub_Category_1'],
    ['parent'=>'Category_1','child'=>'Sub_Category_2'],
    ['parent'=>'Category_1','child'=>'Sub_Category_3'],
    ['parent'=>'Category_1','child'=>'Sub_Category_4'],
    ['parent'=>'Category_2','child'=>'Sub_Category_5'],
    ['parent'=>'Category_2','child'=>'Sub_Category_6'],
    ['parent'=>'Category_2','child'=>'Sub_Category_7'],
    ['parent'=>'Category_2','child'=>'Sub_Category_8'],
    ['parent'=>'Category_2','child'=>'Sub_Category_9'],
    ['parent'=>'Category_3','child'=>null],
    ['parent'=>'Category_4','child'=>null],
    ['parent'=>'Category_5','child'=>null]
];

$cat=null;
foreach ($querycategories as $row){
    if($cat!==$row['parent']){
        echo "<b>{$row['parent']}</b>";
    }
    if(!is_null($row['child'])){
        echo "<ul><li>{$row['child']}</li></ul>";
    }
    $cat=$row['parent'];
}
```

Output:

```
<b>Category_1</b>
<ul>
  <li>Sub_Category_1</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Sub_Category_2</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Sub_Category_3</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Sub_Category_4</li>
</ul>

<b>Category_2</b>
<ul>
  <li>Sub_Category_5</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Sub_Category_6</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Sub_Category_7</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Sub_Category_8</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Sub_Category_9</li>
</ul>

<b>Category_3</b>

<b>Category_4</b>

<b>Category_5</b>
```

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f77bf8/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE categories
    (`id_category` int, `category_name` varchar(14), `category_father` int)
;

INSERT INTO categories
    (`id_category`, `category_name`, `category_father`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Home', 0),
    (2, 'Category_1', 1),
    (3, 'Category_2', 1),
    (4, 'Category_3', 1),
    (5, 'Category_4', 1),
    (6, 'Category_5', 1),
    (7, 'Sub_Category_1', 2),
    (8, 'Sub_Category_2', 2),
    (9, 'Sub_Category_3', 2),
    (10, 'Sub_Category_4', 2),
    (11, 'Sub_Category_5', 3),
    (12, 'Sub_Category_6', 3),
    (13, 'Sub_Category_7', 3),
    (14, 'Sub_Category_8', 3),
    (15, 'Sub_Category_9', 3)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
    c1.category_name as parent_name
  , c2.category_name as child_name
  , c1.id_category as parent_id
  , c2.id_category as child_id
FROM categories c1 
inner join categories c2 on c1.id_category = c2.category_father
order by parent_id, child_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f77bf8/1/0)**:

```
| parent_name |     child_name | parent_id | child_id |
|-------------|----------------|-----------|----------|
|        Home |     Category_1 |         1 |        2 |
|        Home |     Category_2 |         1 |        3 |
|        Home |     Category_3 |         1 |        4 |
|        Home |     Category_4 |         1 |        5 |
|        Home |     Category_5 |         1 |        6 |
|  Category_1 | Sub_Category_1 |         2 |        7 |
|  Category_1 | Sub_Category_2 |         2 |        8 |
|  Category_1 | Sub_Category_3 |         2 |        9 |
|  Category_1 | Sub_Category_4 |         2 |       10 |
|  Category_2 | Sub_Category_5 |         3 |       11 |
|  Category_2 | Sub_Category_6 |         3 |       12 |
|  Category_2 | Sub_Category_7 |         3 |       13 |
|  Category_2 | Sub_Category_8 |         3 |       14 |
|  Category_2 | Sub_Category_9 |         3 |       15 |
```

Comment: ok this seems to work, could you please indicate how to show the result in the form of a list or something similar to what I ask in the question? Thank you.